# postgis and geodjango *and* in filter

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I have a filter, that is working but I want to add more brains to it by looking for anything that is +- 12 days

So I came up with this:

```
last_date = firstPointCheck.acquisition_date - timedelta(days=12)
next_date = firstPointCheck.acquisition_date + timedelta(days=12)

object_list2 = object_list.filter(center__distance_lte=(firstPointCheck.center, D(m=deltaCenter)), acquisition_date__lte=firstPointCheck.acquisition_date, acquisition_date__gte=last_date)
```

I am not sure how to and the dates so I can find everything greater than and equal to last date and less than or equal next date?

Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if date of your object is in specified range using [Django's `range` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range). It will look like this:

```
last_date = firstPointCheck.acquisition_date - timedelta(days=12)
next_date = firstPointCheck.acquisition_date + timedelta(days=12)

object_list2 = object_list.filter(center__distance_lte=(firstPointCheck.center, D(m=deltaCenter)), acquisition_date__range=[last_date, next_date])
```

`range` lookup in django is inclusive, that means range will include start and end value. It is equivalent to:

```
last_date = firstPointCheck.acquisition_date - timedelta(days=12)
next_date = firstPointCheck.acquisition_date + timedelta(days=12)

object_list2 = object_list.filter(center__distance_lte=(firstPointCheck.center, D(m=deltaCenter)), acquisition_date__lte=next_date, acquisition_date__gte=last_date)
```

Comment: awesome ty that range is what I was looking for.